# Applet AccessControlException access denied

Tags: java, security, applet, accesscontrolexception, jlayer

I am trying to reference JLayer.

```
<applet
code="AppStart.class"
height="480"
width="640"
archive="jl1.0.jar, AnApplet.jar"
</applet>
```

I keep getting this error on the console

```
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.security.AccessControlException: 
  access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup")
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.SecurityManagerHelper.checkAccessHelper(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.AWTAppletSecurityManager.checkAccess(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ThreadGroup.checkAccess(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.init(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$DefaultThreadFactory.newThread(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.processWorkerExit(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any help?

This is the first time I am using a referenced jar. My other applets work fine.

Comment: This is JLayer the audio library, not `javax.swing.JLayer`, right?

Answer (score -1):

The referenced jar isn't signed and it is trying to create a thread, which isn't allowed in unsigned jars in applets.

Sign it.

Comment: Eh? You can create threads for unsigned code (within your own thread groups).

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline Eh? The stack trace seems perfectly clear to me. Your comment doesn't.

Comment: Really, unsigned applets have been creating threads since JDK 1.00.